# Using string variable as a name of a sound which I want to play, Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, string, audio

I want to create an app that plays random sound from my raw resouces. It generates a name of a sound, but how do I use that name which is a value of my string variable to start the sound.

```
String[] imena_tonova = {"c3", "c-3", "d3", "d-3", "e3", "f3", "f-3", "g3", "g-3", "a3", "a-3", "b3", "c4", "c-4", "d4", "d-4", "e4", "f4", "f-4", "g4", "g-4", "a4", "a-4", "b4"};
            int range2 = 11 - 0 + 1;
            int randomNum2 =  rn.nextInt(range) + 0;
            String pt = imena_tonova[randomNum2];

final MediaPlayer Play = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.);
            Play.start();
```

What do I have to pass as a second argument in .create() function?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(pt, "raw", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Store identifiers in int[] array.

```
int[] imena_tonova = { R.raw.c3; }
```

Or if you need names associated with the resource you can use Map. Then of course you have to come up with the way of selecting the items randomly.

```
Map<String, Integer> imena_tonova = new HashMap<>();
// Add items to your map
imena_tonova.put("C3", R.raw.c3);
```